# Element always on top

Tags: jquery, overflow, z-index, selectlist

I'm writing a plugin in jquery so that i can style my select lists. I replace the select list with a div and within this div theres an unordered list with position absolute. I want this ul element to always be on top and even ignore overflow hidden. How can i do this with jquery?

Thanks Emil

Comment: I've made a plugin for that called [ScrollectBox](http://www.afekenholm.se/scrollectbox-jquery-plugin). That might suite your needs.

**Edit:** If you want to develop your own you should do that! But it's a possible time-saver if you do not.

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute will already be on top of other statically positioned elements. For further specifications set the `z-index` of the `ul`.

Comment: Thanks but that was not my question. I want my ul element to automatically always be on top. And i want it to override the overflow hidden.

Comment: I'm sorry. Not trying to be rude!

Ok so the styled selecte menu looks like this:

`<div class="select_menu">
   <a href="">Selected option</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Option1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Option2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>` 

And sometimes this code might be in a container with overflow hidden  (Maybe if i wan't to clear a float of some kind). Then i wan't the ul element wich is absolute positioned to override that overflow hidden. I'm sorry if i'm bad at explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

set the css z-index and overflow properties on the containing div